# Bootstrap Vue - change dropdown background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Vue plugin - https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

I need to change dropdown menu default background when someone select value from dropdown like this.

[image]

[image]

But this is the problem. When someone click dropdown, They toggle "show" class in dropwdown wrapper. No any class new class for red color highlighted div.

[image]

I tried to style .dropdown-toggle class but it overrides default style only. Any solution?

```
.dropdown-toggle{
  background-color: #FF5722;
  border-color: #FF5722;
}
```

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/o2gqmqzy/)**

Comment: try setting the style for button instead of .dropdown-toggle

Comment: No luck, Same result

Comment: `.show>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle {background-color: #FF5722}`

make sure your custom css is loaded after the buttons.scss file style

Comment: When someone click and select value, .show class removes from div. Then this is\n working.

Comment: Your Fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/o2gqmqzy/1/

Answer (score -5, accepted):

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropleft</span>
```

In the place of btn btn-secondary  change button classes like danger,primary, etc.... for more information follow this link

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in style. ex:

```js
  <b-form-select
  options="[1, 2, 3]"
  style="background: red">
</b-form-select>
```

or create a class...