# Rendering custom styles in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to add some custom styles to a dropdown menu component which uses Bootstrap-Vue. I'm using the documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown).

Here is my template:

```
<div class="container">
  <b-dropdown id="dropdownMenuButton" text="Dropdown Button" no-caret class="custom-dropdown">
    <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
    <b-dropdown-item>Something else here...</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

I'm finding that I can style #dropdownMenuButton, but when the dropdown renders in the browser it creates a  element inside of #dropdownMenuButton and I can't style that. I've tried doing so like this:

```
<style scoped>
  #dropdownMenuButton > button {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #dropdownMenuButton__BV_toggle_ {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

But no luck. FYI the id of the button that gets created is `dropdownMenuButton__BV_toggle_`.

Comment: maybe you can look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699688/bootstrap-vue-change-dropdown-background

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is beacause you are making the styles scoped to the component and since bootstrap vue dropdown is another component you wont be able to do this with scoped styles.

> https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html

Try removing the scoped attribute like this.

```
<style>
  #dropdownMenuButton > button {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #dropdownMenuButton__BV_toggle_ {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!! Also, of the two different ways to select the button element, is there a preferred method (the parent/child style vs the id of the element)? The id doesn't show up in my template (it's created by bootstrap-vue) so I'm reluctant to reference it.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the `/deep/` keyword to just affect child components, if you don't want to clutter global styles:

```
<style scoped>
  /deep/ #dropdownMenuButton > button {
    width: 100%;
  }

  /deep/ #dropdownMenuButton__BV_toggle_ {
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: +1 you crazy, i have spent almost 2hours and got a bonce of  frustation, finally /deep/ working fine @randy... thanks you...